# Can't set width of an element with js

Tags: javascript, html, css, game-development

I am trying to make a progress bar and I am trying to figure out how to set it's progress in js.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("bar").style.width = "50px"
```

This is the container and the element.

```html
    <div class="project-container">
        <button class="project" id="friendship-bracelet">
            <p>Place Holder</p> 
            <div class="bar">e</div>
        </button>

    </div>
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` returns a collection, not a single element. You need to loop over it or index it.

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName("bar")[0].style.width = "50px"  Please try this

Comment: Oh thats the problem. How can I do this with `getElementsById()`?

Comment: that worked but I need to do a id not a class